# Sublime text: plugin_host is "unable to open channels"

Tags: configuration, sublimetext3

According to info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203541/what-is-the-purpose-of-plugin-host-service-in-sublime-text-3), plugin_host is an external process that is used to execute plugin code. Unfortunately I'm getting an error (see title) and I probably need to configure this process but how? Thanks

- Please note I'm using 32-bit version (https://www.sublimetext.com/3) on *Debian 11*.
- System packages (zip files) are installed in /usr/local/share/sublime-text/Packages
- I created symlink in /usr/local/bin linked to the previous folder
- Python is installed in $HOME/.config/sublime-text-3/Lib/python3.3
- both sublime.py and sublime_plugin.py files are located in $HOME/.config/sublime-text-3/Lib/ folder

**Console output**:

```
UI scale: 1.002 (gtk text scale)
startup, version: 3211 linux x32 channel: stable
executable: /usr/local/bin/sublime
working dir: /
packages path: /home/fox/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages
state path: /home/fox/.config/sublime-text-3/Local
zip path: /usr/local/bin/Packages
zip path: /home/fox/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["Markdown", "Vintage"]
pre session restore time: 0.320594
startup time: 1.57776
first paint time: 1.8247
error: plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until Sublime Text has been restarted
```

**Preferences.sublime-settings:**

```
{
"update_check": false,
"color_scheme": "Packages/dark.scheme",
"tab_size": 4,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
"trim_automatic_white_space": true,
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
"ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
"detect_indentation" : false,
"copy_with_empty_selection": false,
"find_selected_text": true,
"detect_slow_plugins": false,
"auto_complete_delay": 500,
"font_face" : "Source Code Pro",
"font_options":
[
    "directwrite"
],
"font_size": 14,
"highlight_line": true,
"ignored_packages": ["Markdown", "Vintage"]
}

❯ /usr/local/bin/plugin_host
Unexpected number of arguments, expected 2
❯ /usr/local/bin/plugin_host --help
unable to open channels
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **entire text** of the error and/or traceback you're getting. If it's an error window, please add a screenshot. Please also open the console (`Ctrl-\``) and copy and paste any messages or tracebacks there related to your problem.

Comment: Additionally, please open **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings`** and copy the contents of `installed_packages` into your question as well.

Comment: **Settings** menu is disabled and I just tried to copy **sublime.py** and **sublime_plugin.py** to /usr/local/bin folder w/ the same result..

Comment: Hmm. I suggest a complete uninstall and reinstall. I'd also recommend upgrading to [Sublime Text 4](https://www.sublimetext.com/download), as there are loads of improvements - it's well worth it. There are [instructions](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html) on how to add the official SublimeHQ repo to your `apt` repositories, which I find very convenient. One difference you'll find is that the command line shortcut is called `subl` instead of `sublime`.